# How does osmosis work?

Tags: osmosis

I have (very) basic knowledge in chemistry.

I am curious as to **why** osmosis works. I read a couple of introductory chemistry books and also searched online but most explanations I found only explained the phenomena (i.e. solvent molecules move through semipermeable membrane from low solute concentration area to high concentration area), but not the reason behind it at the molecular level (i.e. **what** makes more solvent molecules move towards the high solute concentration area than in the reverse direction).

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Osmosis) seems to go a step further:

> ... there is an interaction between the solute and water that counteracts the pressure that otherwise free solute molecules would exert.

And a bit later:

> The virial theorem demonstrates that attraction between the molecules (water and solute) reduces the pressure, and thus the pressure exerted by water molecules on each other in solution is less than in pure water, allowing pure water to "force" the solution until the pressure reaches equilibrium.

I think I understand what it means, but what I don't understand is this: osmotic pressure is said to be a colligative property, i.e. only affected by the concentration of the solute and not by its type. If the reason for osmotic pressure is the attraction between water and solute molecules - wouldn't we expect different osmotic pressures for different kinds of solutes?

Comment: @obe try to think about entropy changes, third law of thermodynamics and remember the fact that in osmosis solutes do not cross membrane.

Comment: @JM97 honestly I don't know much about thermodynamics. I did read about it a little. I read that a system always moves towards a higher entropy state. The explanation didn't go into the low-level mechanics but the way I imagined it was that since free particles move randomly within a system, they are bound to spread out evenly (on average), thus increase the system's entropy. If this physical description is correct (is it..?) - then it makes sense to me that solvent molecules should still go through the permeable membrane at the same rate in both directions... What am I missing here?

Comment: @JM97 yes, but how come the interaction doesn't depend on the type of the solute? Wouldn't the interaction be different depending on the polarity / size / geometry / etc... of the solute?

Comment: @JM97 but "why"? why is there a net flow from pure water into the solution?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49562/discussion-between-jm97-and-obe).

Comment: It does depend on the type of the solute, but it doesn't matter much in the big picture. The main thing that matters is that you have a polar solvent, and you dissolve a polar something in it - the change in the solvent means that there's a net "lack of solvent" on the side with the solution, which manifests as a (thermodynamic) pressure. I think you're missing the point of your quote - the solution is not just a mix of a solvent and something. Why doesn't it matter what the solute is? Because solvent is the important bit - the solute "steals" "water molecules"; only concentration matters.

Comment: there is a answer here https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/167189/osmotic-pressure-definition-clarification/167286#167286 describing how Osmosis works as a molecular level

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to this document (https://arxiv.org/pdf/physics/0305011v1.pdf)

> "Water molecules can pass through the membranes in either direction, and they do. But because the concentration of water molecules is greater in the pure water than in the solution, there is a net flow from the pure water into the solution."
>   **Hydraulic equilibrium is achieved when the lower concentration of water in the high pressure side is balanced by the higher pressure and therefore higher energy pV on that side**

This is the diffusion model of osmosis which is easy to understand at your level.

Comment: Thanks! This paper looks very relevant. I'll try to read it and come back...

Comment: I don't think that your answer answers my question - it doesn't describe the process at the particle level but rather uses derived concepts, however the article you linked to is the most relevant response I received for this question. However, while the article acknowledges that osmosis is not properly explained in a qualitative manner in chemistry texts, I am not sure it itself does it properly. It seems to go a bit further in the qualitative description but then jumps to equations instead of following through. Or maybe I just lack sufficient background to thoroughly understand...

Answer (score 1):

To first order the solute doesn't matter, though it probably has a small influence. The driving force for osmosis is entropic. The osmotic pressure then is not due to the forces between the solute and solvent, but mostly from the fact that you can mix the two together.

Indeed, osmosis works even when there's less interaction between the solvent and solute, but at some point, the solute is no longer soluble in solvent, so there is no mixing.

Comment: Can you explain the forces that are exerted on solvent molecules that cause more of them to move or stay to or at one side of the membrane?

Comment: I think you're looking at this wrong. Imagine a container that only had gas molecules in one half it. What force causes the gas to diffuse into the other half? There is no force, but the molecules are moving, and there is a greater likelihood that they will occupy the whole box than just half of it. Well, osmosis is a kind of diffusion driven by the entropy of mixing. We can describe the fact that the process is favorable by defining a chemical potential, but there is no force per se that is operating.

Comment: I actually mentioned my understanding of the phenomena of gas filling up the whole box in a comment above. It is my understanding that free particles are in constant movement in random directions, and as such it makes sense to me that they will fill out a container evenly. I admit I have some open questions about the constant movement of particles as well but let's take it as an axiom for now. I still don't see how it explains osmosis. With a membrane that is not a barrier for water, according to the analogy, and ignoring interactions with the solute, I'd expect water to spread out evenly

Comment: See, that's the issue. It _does_ spread out evenly, but you're using the wrong definition of evenly. A simplistic way to think about it is that when you add the solute, "evenly" requires that you need more water to make it look like the other side that doesn't have solute.

Comment: @Zhe is correct in writing that it is the increase in entropy that drives the process. Entropy here means the increase in probability (number of possible arrangements) which arises from distributing particles throughout a bigger rather than smaller volume.  As the solute becomes diluted its entropy increases.

Answer (score 0):

Two factors are involved. First: the Gibbs free energy or chemical potential of the molecules. This is a function of the temperature which results in their random velocities and the entropy of the molecules, their concentrations.  With no physical constraints and ignoring solvation effects and chemical reactions diffusion occurs until the solution is homogeneous. Entropy is maximized at constant energy; the free energy is minimized.

Second: the semipermeable membrane. These can be natural or synthetic and work on two general principles: The membrane either has holes small enough to sort molecules or a chemical composition that is selectively soluble to specialized chemicals, with possibly a combination of both. An example is one's skin. Skin is hydrophobic with sweat glands to pass water and can be very permeable to small organic solvents.

Osmosis involves two solutions with different chemical potentials and a membrane selective to one or more components of the solutions and impermeable to others. [The selectivity can be very high but is not absolute there is an efficiency.] The solutions are separated by the membrane. The permeable molecules diffuse thru the membrane at rates determined by their chemical potentials until the chemical potentials are equal and the free energy change is zero. The equality can be equal concentrations or equal collision frequencies and can be influenced or hastened by gravity or a centrifuge or by temperature or electrical forces.

If the solute reacts minimally with the solvent, ie. a reasonably ideal solution, osmosis is dependent on the chemical potential, activity, of the permeable substance and reasonably independent of the nonpermeable substances.

Answer (score -1):

I think you can find what you are looking for by googling "entropy"
http://www.mpcfaculty.net/mark_bishop/solubility_entropy.htm

To summarize the article : "In general, particles of matter tend to become more dispersed (spread out)."

My guess is that it has something to do with the leonard jones force. Here is a video I made where the "text" is like a positive force and all the particle are a negative force. So the particles are slightly attracted to the text but when they get too close to the text, they get launched away (because I made the repulsive force to be huge).

-
But in reality every single particle would have a positive and a negative so they all are attracted to each other but push away from each other once they get close enough. https://vimeo.com/182775330

Comment: I read the article. Interesting, thanks :) I agree that entropy seems to be key here. However, I still have difficulty with this. I think my main issue is `natural tendency toward greater dispersal`. I understand why it's the case with gas, at the atomic level, and why it's the case when mixing water and ethanol. I imagine the particles and their random movements and I can understand why they disperse. However applying this to osmosis is a leap I don't understand because when I imagine solvent molecules moving freely, they end up with the same amount on both sides of the membrane...

Comment: On one side, the atoms are repelling each other more because they are concentrated. But after they have the same amount on both sides, the pressure is equal....I imagine.

Comment: @obe It's in the wikipedia quote you have in your question - when you dissolve something in a solvent, it changes both the something and the solvent. The water no longer behaves entirely like water, which in this scenario means that the side with solvent "feels" like it has less water than it really does. Read up on how solutions (or e.g. acids) work - it's not just a mechanical mix of two chemicals. Think about a salt solution - pure water is an isolant, pure salt is an isolant, but dissolve some salt in pure water, and you get a great conductor - both are "torn apart" in a solution.

Comment: @Luaan I realize that but I'm having trouble with the "feel" concept... if I believed water could "feel" things, I'd post on homeopathy.stackexchange.com :) jokes aside, having learnt a little chemistry, I now understand the molecular forces that underlie various macro phenomena. For example, I can explain why water is liquid in room temperature while oxygen is gas, using the intrinsic properties of the nucleus and its sub-particles. I'd like to be able to do the same with the osmosis phenomena...

Comment: @obe You know how when you dissolve salt in water, at some point, the salt stops dissolving? At that point, the water "feels" like there's no water - the solution is saturated. I hope you have no problem with this concept? Why is that so? The molecules of water that are already engaged with a solute cannot bind with another molecule of a solute, so there is less water available for solving the solute. This manifests as thermodynamic pressure across the membrane. And you're quite confused - only electrons matter for your example. Nuclei only matter in so far as they pair with those electrons.

Comment: @Luaan as far as I know the explanation for saturated solution is that the reaction works in both ways (i.e. solute dissolved and precipitates at the same time). The solution is said to be saturated when the rate of the reaction in both directions is the same. The exact point when it happens depends on several factors such as polarity, geometry, temperature, etc... It can be explained in these terms without using words like "feels"... can you explain how this manifests as thermodynamic pressure across the membrane?

Comment: @obe You've explained it yourself. How can you not see it? I give up :)

Answer (score -4):

As far I as I understood from my professor
Osmosis is the flow of water from higher solute concertation to lower through a semipermeable membrane
That solely because of increased collision between water and solute in the high solute concentration area
Now the question arises why water and not the solute movement. Solute being less in size than water technically should move. But here comes thdy(thermodynamics) in play
The let's say the solute here is salt. That when added in water dissociates into Na+ and Cl- now in order to nullify the charge and satisfy the entropy loss the water arranges it self around Na+ in hydration shells this hydration shell helps in dispersal of the +ive charge carried by the Na+ and similar hydration shells are made with Cl- to it's only the orientation of H and OH differs
Na+ makes hydration shell with OH oriented outwards while Cl- with H of water oriented outward.

So the hydrated Na+ and hydrated Cl- are to large to pass through the semi permeable membrane and that's is why it's the water..
Hope it helps. Feel free the correct if sth is wrong